# Exclude words from stringex act_as_url?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stringex

I use Stringex to generate slugs for an ActiveRecord model. My code is as follows:

**product.rb**

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_url :name, url_attribute: :url, sync_url: true, limit: 50, replace_whitespace_with: "_"
  def to_param
    slug
  end
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
get '', to: 'product#show',:as => 'product'
```

So if a url of a product is `search`, the routes will be `/search` and I have a `/search` route already. I want to exclude some words that stringex should not use as a url attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `:blacklist` attribute for the `acts_as_url` method. Add `blacklist: %w{new search}` by default the value of `blacklist` attribute is `%w{new}` to avoid conflicting with the rails default `new` route.

Your code should be as follows:

**product.rb**

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
 acts_as_url :name, url_attribute: :url, sync_url: true,\
  limit: 50, replace_whitespace_with: "_", blacklist: %w{new search}
 def to_param
   slug
 end
end
```